# __init__ arguments differ from object attributes

Tags: design, object-oriented, python, object-oriented-design, patterns-and-practices

Is the following class definition a good design?

```
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self,num1,num2):
        self.complicated_tree = __class__.object_creator(num1,num2)

    @classmethod
    def tree_creator(cls,num1,num2):
        return num1+num2 #in practice, this functions would be really long
                         #and would return a whole tree of numbers

    #my tree doesn't need all the standard traversing etc. methods, just very few
    #special ones
    def specialized_method1(self): 
        pass

    def specialized_method2(self): 
        pass
```

I'm a beginner in Python and so far every class `__init__` method  arguments were identical to the object attributes.  In this case, this is not true anymore, because this class shall contain objects that first need to be constructed in a complicated way: a special type of tree that I first need to generate in 20 lines of code using `num1` and `num2`.

Is this defining such a class good design/practice? Or should I generate the whole tree outside of the class, so that the tree's `__init __` method is

```
    def __init__(self,tree):
        self.tree = tree
```

and the `tree_creator` function is a separate function outside the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your class requires complicated data structures to work correctly, then there's nothing wrong with creating them in the constructor - it helps ensure that instances of that class are never in a surprising "not yet usable" state that you'd have to remember to check for. If that makes the constructor take a long time, that's just the way it is. And there is nothing wrong with constructor arguments differing from the values of internal fields.

Whether to construct a complicated tree within or without the class depends on the purpose of the class. If the class is specifically *about* that tree, e.g. a class representing your file system, then such code usually belongs within the class. If the class represents something totally different, but knows how to use a tree-shaped data structure for some specific purpose, e.g. a product configurator using a decision tree, then it *could* be more appropriate to construct the tree outside the class, or at least within a nested helper class.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly fine that the attributes of an object are different from the arguments passed to the constructor that was used to create the object (the `__init__` method is a constructor).

In languages with overloading, it is even possible to specify multiple constructors that each take a different set of arguments, while the attributes of the object are the same each time.

---

The attributes of an object represent the state of an object and should be in such a form that all methods and properties of the object can be implemented without too much effort or duplicated calculations.

The arguments of a constructor should provide the information that is needed to create an object and they should be in a format that it reasonably convenient for the users of the object.

If there is a significant difference between the two representations, then the constructor should perform the required calculations/transformations.